# Google Charts Showing error in alignment when displayed inside a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, bootstrap-modal

When I am trying to display a Graph/Chart on a Bootstrap Modal. It shows error in alignment. It works fine when it is placed outside the modal. Check out the codes that follows:

**Javascript:** This is the code used to draw the chart.

```
google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar"]});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', 'Absent'],
          ['A', 2],
          ['B', 3],
          ['C', 4],
          ['D', 3],
          ['E', 6]
        ]);

        var options = {
          chartArea: {width: 50},

          legend: { position: 'none' },

          axes: {
            x: {
              0: { side: 'top'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          },
          bar: { groupWidth: '90%' }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
};
```

**HTML:** This is the html code of the bootstrap modal. Here the div "top_x_div" is the chart holder.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="showGraph" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Graph</h4>
          </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                  <div id="top_x_div" ></div>


              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

              </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

The screenshot is given below:
[image]

Here, the assigned values are A:2,B:3,C:4,D:3,E:6
But here the graph is aligned with error and starts from the point 4 and the labels A,B,C... overlaps the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Got the Answer. I just called the drawStuff() after a few seconds delay, on the modal show event. The code is given below:

```
$('#showGraph').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

        setTimeout(
        function() 
        {
          drawStuff();
        }, 500);

    })
```

Now it works fine